# How to Show Object Multiplicity

Tags: research, design, affordance

I am creating a visual programming language. In this language objects are represented as rectangles, like this:

[image]

I thought that the best way to represent that an object is actually a collection of elements (a list, set, etc) would be to use "depth", like this:

[image]

Is there any UX research to support choosing this kind of representation?

Comment: That could be confused as a shadow. I'd recommend making the stack 3 rectangles. Just to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the approach you have as it does show depth by the superimposition of two images on top of each other. Apple iPad image galleries also use a similar layout as demonstrated below: [image]

You could also enhance on your proposed design by looking at a stack approach like this : [image]

[image]

Comment: Is the a "common" direction to use? your examples show three different directions. Which one is the best? and also, is there any research backing this usage?

Comment: @vainolo I don't think there's a significant difference, they all indicate a "stack" though the middle one is fairly abstract